# HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized with OData generated endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, odata, sap-gateway

I am trying to generate the objects of an API OData Service in my application.

This service is a vendoring app by ERP SAP (version 2.0). The authorization header property is a `Basic` credential.

After I add the header and click the button to generate, the server returns an error 401 (not authorized), but the credentials are ok.

[image: Image1]

In the Postman the request returns the metadata correctly.

Analyzing the request with a sniffer http was verified that the wizard sends two requests. The first request returns a status 200 (OK), but the second request returns the status 401 and throws the error in the wizard.

[image: Image2]

How can I configure the wizard to stop sending two requests or simply add the header property with the credentials in the second request?

Comment: It can be any authorization issue, whatever it's the credentials or any missing authorization within the SAP system. Ask the SAP system administrator to trace all authorization issues.

Comment: please add .Net Core version